# How can i scan a ble device always

Tags: android, beacon

How can scan a ble device always even app killed or closed by recent apps ..i tried with  foreground service but when app closed from recent apps service also destroyed..anyone knoe about this?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same thing that when the app was closed from recent activity the background scanning stopped in redmi k20 pro but the same was not observed with Mi A1 and Nokia android phones.
In k20 pro also this was observed when I used "close all recent apps" but when I closed just the app, it was still running in the background and did not get killed.
I believe there are some os level tweaks done by few android companies that are causing this issue. Please check it with other phones as well.

Comment: You can also try out this repository, this has working code for BLE foreground service https://github.com/helloworldkr/Bluetooth-ble-beamer-and-scanner-for-tracing-corona-virus-infected-individual